# dynamic mapping of columns

Tags: sql, ssis

I have two table source, destination.
The destination table has fixed columns ID,Product_name,Product_description.

In the source table there is three columns ID,Product_name,Product_description.

I want to map the columns in the source table to the similar columns in the destination table using SSIS.

The issue is that the column name ID in the source table may change to ProductID,uniqueID in the future.

column name Product_name in the source table may change to Name,name_of_product in the future.

column name Product_description in the source table may change to describe,desc in the future.

I want to map the columns of the source table to the destination table even if the column name changes, without mapping the columns manually everytime.

in the sense without touching the package.

Please help me with this.

Regards,
Preethi

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to map the source columns with distanation columns dynamically. We need to use Script Task to handle these kind of scenarios. If you know Vb.Net or C#.net then we can write the script to read the source columns and map the same to destination collumns dynamically.

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).